# Formatting date and time to pm/am. Php

Tags: php, datetime

Could anyone suggest please. How to show time in pm/am format. I use such code. I formated dates/times according to the chosen locale.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $last_ticket['created_on']);

    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        Tickets::returnLocale(),
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    );
    return $formatter->format($dt);
```

It return **Wednesday, 10 August 2022 at 21:42** but I need **10 August 2022 at 09:42 am**

What appropriate pattern ? **$formatter->setPattern('');**

Comment: So...have you checked the PHP documentation for what you can use instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s`? It's all listed there, showing you which characters in the format represent what things. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php . It's unclear where you're stuck, other than potentially not having yet started to look up the information you need.

Comment: Relevant bits from that page, `A Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem` and
`g 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros` ...  or `h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$last_ticket['created_on']` is your date in the `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format (eg `2022-09-13 13:59:30`), you need this:

```php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $last_ticket['created_on']);
return $date->format('d F Y \a\t h:i a');
```

Is should return something like "13 September 2022 at 01:59 pm".

As mentioned in the comments, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php for more details.

**edit**

If you want to use the `IntlDateFormatter` you can do it like so:

```php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
  Tickets::returnLocale(),
  IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
  IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
  null,
  null,
  "d LLLL Y 'at' hh:mm a"
);
return $formatter->format($dt);
```

`IntlDateFormatter` is actually using a different syntax than `DateTime::format`, check here: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/

Comment: Bartek Suski, It dose not fits me. I need to use class IntlDateFormatter. I formated dates/times according to the chosen locale.

Comment: $formatter->setPattern(');

Comment: @Jack88 I edited the answer to include `IntlDateFormatter`.

Comment: LLLL is used when the month is alone (example январь in Russian). MMMM is used in the context. Example: "10 января, 2014".

Answer (score 0):

When using the `IntlDateFormatter` you can either specify a fixed pattern according to the [ICU documentation](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#formatting-dates) or try a combination of different date and time constants.
If you use the constants, the format is different for almost every language.

```
$dt = date_create('2022-08-10 21:42');
$locale = 'en';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        $locale,
        IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
        IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
        null,
        null,
        //"d MMMM Y 'at' hh:mm a"
);
$date = $formatter->format($dt);
echo $date;
```

Result en: August 10, 2022 at 9:42:00 PM

Result it: 10 agosto 2022 21:42:00

To test an ICU format pattern, just uncomment it. Using a fixed pattern with at will look odd in non-enlish languages.

Example: 10 августа 2022 at 09:42 PM

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XvhQ5